# How do I force Jupyter Lab to revert a file

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, python-black

I have a Jupyter Notebook open in Jupyter Lab. I run black to reformat the code in the open Jupyter Notebook. If I try to save the file, Jupyter Lab raises

> "notebook.ipynb" has changed on disk since the last time it was opened
> or saved. Do you want to overwrite the file on disk with the version
> open here, or load the version on disk (revert)?

How can I revert the Jupyter Notebook without try to save it?

Comment: Are you using a jupyterlab widget to run black or the command line app? And does clicking “revert” not do what you’re looking for for some reason?

Comment: I'm using the command line. Click in "revert" from the pop up menu does what I'm looking but I was looking how to avoid try to save and select revert.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer at `File` > `Reload from Disk`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem.

Go to Kernel pull down menu, select "Restart & Clear Output". Then, the Jupyter Notebook will be restored to initial status, and all output will be erased.

[Please see attached picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oPBB.png)